# How can I use getChar()?

Tags: c#

I have this code in java :

```
instr = instr.trim();
char[] c = new char[instr.length()];
instr.getChars(0,c.length,c,0);
```

How to write this code in C#?

Comment: What did you try? We don't do code translations here.

Comment: Can to use, that's not English.

Comment: @gdoron: It's definitely english, the words are very recognisable. It's even possible to understand the meaning, even if the grammar is totally off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
int startIndex = 1;
int length = 2;
char[] chars = instr
      .Where((c, i) => i >= startIndex && i < startIndex+length).ToArray();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kAvJj4)

If you just want to copy *all* chars into a new `char[]`, you can  use [`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx). If you want part of a string as string, you can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `toCharArray` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ToCharArray` method:

```
instr = instr.Trim();
char[] c = instr.ToCharArray();
```